# Permissions error when trying to allow Domain-Wide-Delegation for a service account: "Sign in with an administrator account..."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nodemailer, service-accounts

**I'm trying to allow Domain-Wide-Delegation for an account from here:**

[image]

**However, clicking on "View Google Workspace Admin Console" redirects me to a sign in screen, where even if I try to sign in with the account with the service account, I get this ERROR:**

[image]

**My understanding is that I need to have a Google Service account to allow my app (in production) to be able to access gmail, which is why I need a service account.
Please help me understand how do I allow permission for Domain-Wide-Delegation for this service account. How does a Service Account relate to a Google Workspace account and Google Cloud Identity?
I'm trying to use Gmail API with nodemailer like this:**

```
try {
    let transporter = await nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        type: "OAuth2",
        user: 'clippingpathasia08@gmail.com',
        serviceClient: process.env.SERVICE_CLIENT,
        privateKey: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
      },
    });
    const mailOptions = {
```

**ERROR:**

```
Sign in with an administrator account
To sign in to admin.google.com, use an administrator account for a managed Google service, such as Google Workspace or Cloud Identity. Learn more about Google accounts
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after finding some leads :

- Google Accounts are not the same as Google Workspace Account ( formally known as G Suit Account )
- You can have a Google service account under either Google Account / Google Workspace account. But having a Google Service account under your google account cannot be helpful as this service account cannot be delegated permission.
- **Only having a Google Workspace account**, ex `name@mycompany.com`, allows you to have an **Admin role & Admin consol**e , which in turn allows you to grant Domain-Wide-Delegation to your service account. Doing this delegation, your service account  now holds the permission to access, ex Gmail, for all the accounts (like `bob@mycompany.com` or `name2@mycompany.com` ) under your workspace.

Comment: At the end, I did not end up with creating a Google Service account, as its requires ~7 CAD/ user/ month. Instead I, used Resend (https://resend.com/home) to send emails. 
100 emails / day for ever. Perfect for my use case.